# BIND9 as a DNS server refuses requests

Tags: networking, dns, bind

I am trying to set up a DNS server on Amazon Linux using BIND9.
It has to act as a master nameserver for a lot of domains.

I have imported all of the DNS zone files using NamedManager (a web interface that creates bind configration files).

My **/etc/named.conf** is as follows:

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { any; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { any; };
    allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };
};

include "/etc/named.namedmanager.conf";

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};
```

My **/etc/named.namedmanager.conf** (the auto-generated files) is as follows:

```
zone "mydomain.com.dns" IN {
        type master;
        file "mydomain.com.dns.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};
zone "myotherdomain.com.dns" IN {
        type master;
        file "myotherdomain.com.dns.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};
// ... more zones
```

My **/var/named/mydomain.com.zone**

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
$TTL 120
@               IN SOA ns.THISNAMESERVER.com. mymail@mymaindomain.com. (
                        2013111005 ; serial
                        21600 ; refresh
                        3600 ; retry
                        604800 ; expiry
                        120 ; minimum ttl
                )

; Nameservers
mydomain.com.   86400 IN NS ns.THISNAMESERVER.com.
```

---

But when I try to resolve mydomain.com using this DNS server from home I get the following:

```
[me@myhomepc ~]$ host mydomain.com. ns.MYNAMESERVER.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns.MYNAMESERVER.com
Address: <my-nameserver-ip>#53
Aliases: 

Host mydomain.com not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

I tried disabling recursion for 127.0.0.1 (recursion no; in options{}), as I need to be my nameserver to be serving results. In that case I don't get REFUSED but I don't get any answer!

Comment: If you use `nc` does it form a tcp connection on port 53?

Comment: [me@mypc ~]$ nc ns.mynameserver.com 53
gives no output. How do I know?

Comment: try `nc -vz ns.mynameserver.com 53` if it's the old version `nc -v ns.mynameserver.com 53` if it's the newer one

Comment: Usually no output means it didn't connect, though.

Comment: I thought that 5(REFUSED) meant that the server accepted our connection but is refusing to reply to us? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1697403/33204

Comment: Please run this command and report results: `$ dig mydomain.com. @ns.MYNAMESERVER.com`.

Comment: Take a look a this SF Q&A: http://serverfault.com/questions/371774/how-do-you-check-if-a-nameserver-responds-to-recursive-queries

Answer (score 1):

The name you are looking up is not part of any zone that you have.

The zone that you have configured is named `mydomain.com.dns` but you are trying to look up the name `mydomain.com`.

In addition to this it looks like there is out of zone data inside the `mydomain.com.dns` zone, but I can only assume that the problem here is actually the zone name.

For any additional errors you may want to look at your logs and/or `named-checkconf -zj` output.

Comment: (Yes, I know this is and old question but it had been autobumped and the answer hadn't been posted, maybe it can help someone else.)

Answer (score 0):

The config files look OK except that in the file `/var/named/mydomain.com.zone` you need to put an **A record** for mydomain.com, something like this:

Add this line in `/var/named/mydomain.com.zone`:

```
mydomain.com.   IN   A   x.y.z.t
```

and don't forget to update the serial at the beginning of the file and then restart or reload the named service.